# How to query $regex on embedded documents to count distinct values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with documents in the following format:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("abc"), 
    "mobile" : "123456789", 
    "channels" : [
        {
            "name" : "email.xz", 
            "type" : "a", 
            "properties" : [
                {
                    "provider" : "outlook"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "sms", 
            "type" : "sms"
            }
    ], 

}
```

I need to find customers who have at least one channel which the name ends with ".xz", but only if provider exists and has a value, and return the count of customers per channel. For instance:

```
email.xz = 10
sms.xz = 5
push.xz = 7
```

I tried to use the aggregate function below, but it resulted in a count of all the customers that match the criteria.

```
db.consumers.aggregate(
{$match: {"channels.name": {$regex: ".xz$"}, 
"notificationChannels.properties.provider": { $exists: true }}},
{$group: {_id: "channels.name"},
count: {$sum: 1}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array, and then [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) the same way again. The first match is only selecting documents, and you want to filter:

```
db.consumers.aggregate(
  { $match: {
    "channels.name": {$regex: ".xz$"}, 
    "channels.properties.provider": { $exists: true }
  }},
  { $unwind: "$channels" },
  { $match: {
    "channels.name": {$regex: ".xz$"}, 
    "channels.properties.provider": { $exists: true }
  }},
  { $group:{
    "_id": "$channels.name",
    "count": {$sum: 1}
  }}
)
```

Since you want to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on a key from "inside" the array, then you need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) it anyway. Since you only want the array entries that match your conditions, then the only way to do that with a [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) is through a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) after the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

Comment: $match is redundant in this query

Comment: @kailashyogeshwar No it certainly is not. It is of the "utmost importance" that you **always** use an initial stage in any aggregation pipeline that can address an index and ideally reduce results. You appear to be presuming that "every document" will meet the condition and that you only ever need the subsequent `$match` following `$unwind` to filter the array content. Unfortunately you probably picked up that opinion from seeing very bad examples before that do not consider that. Both `$match` stages here are doing two different things.  So it's not a mistake but intentional and good design.

Comment: perhaps using  '_id: "$channels.name"' for the $group, would be more informative?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Thanks. Overzealous copy and paste and did not notice that.

Comment: Thank you.  Never worked with MongoDB, got nowhere with this exercise after a whole day of trying.  The fact that I didn't realize I was using a 3.2 (on Debian) but looking at a 3.6 manual, didn't improve my chances.  Your answer should appear in the tutorials.